# Ada + Fixed Stringss + Stm32 Arm

Tags: string, arm, runtime-error, ada, stm32

How to create a simple function returns a string on a arm platform?

`procedure Main is
   function tst_func return String is
   begin
      return "string";
   end tst_func;
   str : String := tst_func;  --  <-- Doesnt work, runtime error. 
                                -- Adacore gpl compiller, crossdev, arm elf hosted of win os.
                                -- Hardware is smt32f407 discovery board.
begin
...`

Comment: Try with the function returning a fixed length string, e.g. `string(1 .. 6)` instead of unconstrained strings. If that works, the RTS you are using may not support the secondary stack, which is  used for returning unconstrained arrays.

Comment: @Brian Drummond, yeah its work. Is it hardware or software issue? Can i do something with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a bug in the runtime system: if your program doesn’t involve any tasking, the environment task’s secondary stack isn’t set up properly, so when your function tries to return a string it thinks the secondary stack has been exhausted and raises `Storage_Error`.

I have reported this to AdaCore: their recommendation was to include

```
delay until Ada.Real_Time.Clock;
```

in your main program.

The bug will likely be resolved in the next GNAT GPL release.

Comment: Presumably this is just a bodge to force the RTS to make an effort to set things up correctly?

Comment: Brian, yes. I reported it to AdaCore just now, suggesting a simple fix to the RTS: will report back if they do.

Comment: AdaCore also suggest this workround. The code has already been fixed and will, no doubt, be released to us in the next GNAT GPL release. I don’t know if it’ll end up in FSF GCC 5.0 (not there yet!)

Answer (score 2):

The issue here seems to be that using Ada on small embedded CPUs like the STm32 (ARM Cortex)  or the Actel AVR or TI MSP430 often involves compromises, because the platform may not be capable of running a full Ada RTS (Runtime System) including things like tasking.

Instead, a minimal RTS may be supplied, with restrictions specified by pragmas, that doesn't support tasking, or in this case, features requiring the secondary stack. Funnily enough, the RTS for the AVR does include the files `s-secsta.ads,.adb` which implement `package System.Secondary_Stack` so the much more powerful STm32 ought to be capable of it. You could look at the RTS sources supplied with the Adacore GPL package to see if these files are present or not.

So - options.

1) Work around, either using fixed length strings, or a table of string constants, or returning an  `access String` (i.e. pointer) to a string allocated on the heap (don't forget to free it!) though heap use is not normally recommended for embedded programming.

2) Find a better RTS. You can compile and link against a different RTS by supplying `-RTS=...` arguments to the compiler. [Here is a thread](https://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=2188035&type=member&item=5902805049809055747&trk=groups_items_see_more-0-b-ttl) discussing alternative RTS strategies for this CPU.

Comment: The RTS supplied with the AdaCore GPL ARM compilers only supports the Ravenscar profile ([ARM D.13](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-D-13.html)), which includes amongst other restrictions `No_Implicit_Heap_Allocations` - i.e., in GNAT, no secondary stack.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I haven't tried that compiler yet so I didn't have the info to hand.

Comment: Actually, Brian, the RTS _does_ have secondary stack, and it _doesn’t_ violate `No_Implicit_Heap_Allocations` (presumably the word “stack” has something to do with this); but as Jamshoot says, the program crashes.

Comment: That suggests Option 2 is off the table, but further information is needed to find the issue using the current RTS. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, please accept Simon's answer. Mine may have started the ball rolling but he's put the work in to get to the bottom of it.